# Uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag (NameError) - jquery_datepicker gem error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Just installed the jquery-datepicker gem and have used a few of the helpers in the view:

```
<div><%= f.datepicker 'date' %></div>
<div><%= f.datetime_picker 'date', :dateFormat => "yy-mm-dd" %></div>
```

and this one

```
<h5><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i><%= datepicker_input "event","date" %></h5>
```

and when I reset the server I'm getting the following error (and the server isn't starting now):

> usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/jquery_datepicker-0.4/lib/app/helpers/form_helper.rb:33:in `': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag (NameError)

Full error

https://gist.github.com/naushadparpia/7819419

Answer (score 2):

Are you using rails 4 or rails 3?  You have tags for both.  It would seem you are using rails 4, ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag is from Rails 3 and is not in Rails 4.  Looking at the jquery-datepicker gem [github page](https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker), it looks like that gem is not rails 4 compatible.

Somebody tried to fix it to make it work in Rails 4 [here](https://github.com/foodforarabbit/jquery_datepicker/tree/636331e04a9e39e3a367af6ae548837d0b2fa20b).  Good luck!

Comment: thanks so much @RustyToms, any idea how I might implement the Rails 4 fix that has been added to the lib?

Comment: I've never done it myself, but [here are some instructions](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/gitgem.htm).